# Publishing WFS and Feature Access through ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, wfs, feature-service

I'm trying to publish a large number of MXD files to my ArcGIS Server with an ArcPy script. Here's the overview of how I'm doing this

```
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(...)
con = r'C:\...'
service = currentMXD[:-4]
sddraft = wrkspc + '\\sdfiles\\' + service + '.sddraft'
sd = wrkspc + '\\sdfiles\\' + service + '.sd'
arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', con, True, 'etc')
arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForSD(sddraft)
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
```

Pretty much following the example code of how to publish using an MXD file. Now,
I want to add WFS and Feature Access capabilities when publishing these MXDs, which seems like it should be simple because you just need to check the boxes off when publishing manually, but I can't find how to do so. Does anyone know of a way to do so?

Comment: Possible hints [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91480/how-to-specify-map-service-parameters-when-publishing-with-arcpy) ?